# MongoDB performance in SAFE mode

Tags: java, performance, mongodb

How does setting the WriteConcern flag to SAFE in the java driver affects MongoDB performances?

Comment: This may be a stupid question I ask, but: you can imagine yourself easily by *thinking* that performance goes down. By how much? Measure it yourself with *your* system and *your* data.

Comment: It's a genuine question since Mongo does fire-and-forget by default. Obviously it's gonna slow down, but I was looking for an answer based on how other people dealt with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slows it down significantly (as you would expect).

Without the "SAFE" flag, MongoDB drivers operate in "Fire & Forget" mode. So the `update` command is sent to the server and then the driver continues on. If there is an error with the write or the server dies before the change happens, the client knows nothing about it.

With the "SAFE" flag, the drivers do both the `update` command and the `getLastError()` command. That second command will not complete until the update actually happens on the DB. At the very least, you are sending two commands instead of one (*so it's 50% slower*).

In my experience it's actually 5x-20x slower. Of course, this makes sense because actually writing the data is the slow part of this whole piece.

Note that without the SAFE flag, certain exceptions will never happen. For example, you will never get a duplicate key exception.

If you plan to use MongoDB as a typical database (analogous to say MySQL), you need to use  *at least* "SAFE" mode and replica sets. Otherwise, you need "JOURNAL" mode with a single box. I you use JOURNAL mode, you will notice that performance starts to look at lot like regular SQL.

Comment: Your answer is not 100% correct. "Of course, this makes sense because actually writing the data is the slow part of this whole piece." That's not necessarily the case, as "safe" mode only signifies that the insert/update has been applied in *memory*. For ensuring things are on disk, you'll need "fsync".

Comment: @Derick: there are two problems with your answer. #1: You can also ensure data is on disk by using ensuring that it has been journaled (which is much faster than waiting for the fsync). #2: at no point do I mention the word "disk" anywhere in my post. You and I both know that with MongoDB getting data to the disk is a secondary concern.

Comment: BTW, if you want to make a canonical answer to this question, you actually have access to the MongoDB documentation. So rather than complain about a word that I never used or an implication that I never made, why not provide the 100% answer on the MongoDB docs?